# What is difference between varagrs using (int...i) and (Integer...i)

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

When I run this code with two different varargs (Integer...i) and (int...i), the output of code with (Integer...i) displayed warning message and the other was run correctly. But I cannot understand the different between them.

```
public static void test(Integer...i) {

    System.out.println("int array");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(null);
}
```

When run this code, warnings message display like that.

```
File.java:11: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
    test(null);
         ^cast to Integer for a varargs call
```

But when I change varargs (Integer...i) to(int...i), code was run perfectly.

```
public static void test(int...i) {

    System.out.println("int array");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(null);
}
```

And output display is:

```
int array
```

Comment: You realize that `Integer` is a class for wrapper objects while `int` is a built-in primitive? If so you should realize there _is_ a difference between vargs of the two. Hint: `Integer...` is actually just another way for passing an `Integer[]` array and hence when you pass `null` the compiler doesn't know that should be null: the first element of the array or the array itself?

Comment: Try `test((Integer)null);`

Comment: The first one, 'null' is the first Integer passed in. ie it accepts Object[]. The second one the array is treated as null.

Comment: this just means the mismatch  in format

Comment: The compiler does not "know" what you want: `Integer[] arr = null` or `Integer[] arr = new Integer[] {null}`. For the `int[]` it is easy because you cannot create `new int[] {null}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One key thing to remember is that varargs are compiled to creating and accepting arrays. That is,

```
void test(Integer... i)
```

and

```
void test(Integer[] i)
```

are effectively the same thing. *(Waves hands. There are some bookkeeping differences.)* When you call it:

```
test(i1, i2, i3);
```

...the call is really

```
test(new Integer[] { i1, i2, i3 });
```

And that's the source of the issue here.

With `Integer...`, when you use `test(null)`, you're saying you want to pass `null` as the first integer of what might be several, because `Integer` is an reference type and so `null` can match it. So you're passing an inexact type for the first entry in the array, like this `test(new Integer[] { null })`.

With `int...`, when you use `test(null)`, the `null` can't be the first `int` because `int` is not a reference type. So the compiler determines that you're passing `null` as the *array* itself. You can't be trying to do `test(new int[] { null })` because that would be invalid; so you must be doing `test((int[])null)`. Since `null` is perfectly acceptable for an `int[]` parameter, the call compiles without warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
test(null);
```

- `null` could be an `Integer` when `Integer...`
- `null` could be an `Integer[]` when `Integer`
- `null` cannot be an int value, when `int...`
- `null` must be an `int[]` when `int`

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in the way `null` is interpreted in both methods.

The first method `public static void test(Integer...i)` requires either a list of parameters of  type `Integer` or an array thereof, `Integer[]`. So if you pass `test(null);` the compiler is confused, because `null` can be both types. That means you could pass either a `Integer` or a `Integer[]`. An explicit cast is required.

In the second case `public static void test(int...i)` requires parameters of type `int` which is a *primitive* type or an array thereof, `int[]` which would be a reference type. Since primitive types can't be `null`, the compiler understands that you're passing the `null` as `int[]` and thus doesn't give you a warning.